# VTK: How to remove the limit 0f window size when I use offScreenRenderingOn?

Tags: c#, vtk

For some reason,I need a vtkRenderWindow of size 10000x10000,I used OffScreenRenderingOn to Create a window in memory,but it didn't work.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   window.OffScreenRenderingOn();
   window.SetSize(10000,10000);
   window.FullScreenOn();
   int[] size = window.GetSize();
   Console.WriteLine("Actual window size：{0}，{1}",size[0],size[1]);
}
```

And the result always 1920,1050

Comment: The FullScreenOn() limits the size to the size of your screen. Omit this, then you can made your renderwindow larger

Comment: that didn't work too

Comment: I have tested this using the C++ API and the Python wrapper for VTK9.0 and it works for me. If you need assistance, you need to provide a fully working example...

Comment: I put python code downstairs, but windowsize is still 1920x1080

Answer (score 0):

#!/usr/bin/env python

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import vtkmodules.all as vtk

def main():
colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()

```
# Create a sphere
cylinderSource = vtk.vtkCylinderSource()
cylinderSource.SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
cylinderSource.SetRadius(5.0)
cylinderSource.SetHeight(7.0)
cylinderSource.SetResolution(100)

# Create a mapper and actor
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(cylinderSource.GetOutputPort())
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.GetProperty().SetColor(colors.GetColor3d("Cornsilk"))
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
actor.GetProperty()

# Create a renderer, render window, and interactor
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.SetOffScreenRendering(1)
renderWindow.SetSize(10000,10000)

renderWindow.FullScreenOn()
aa = renderWindow.GetSize()
print(aa)
#### output is (1920,1080)

renderWindow.SetWindowName("Cylinder")
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

# Add the actor to the scene
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.SetBackground(colors.GetColor3d("DarkGreen"))

# Render and interact
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
main()

Comment: As I said earlier, you cannot use `FullScreenOn()`. This limits the size to that of your screen

Comment: thanks!!! I tested fullScreenOn() with C#, without this order,output was 290x290, I tried as you said using python, it worked!! I think, it might be the problem of VTK's version. In C#,I can only use vtk5.8, however,vtk9.0 is helpful in python. Thanks again!!!